# LEGO model of USB socket?

Tags: piece-usage

I am looking to make a LEGO version of my laptop. Is there a LEGO brick or set of LEGO bricks that would form a USB socket?

Comment: What is the scale of your model?

Comment: @pcantin Roughly 3 blocks:1 inch

Answer (score 3):

At a larger scale, a similar hole that includes an indent that can accept circular connectors, preferably 3-brick long for anchoring, for a true connection. But at that size, it would be roughly 3.2 times the size of a typical laptop.

For a tiny model, just do a 2 x 1/3 x 1 brick hole, into which a no-studs plate can be slipped.

If you are going for an actual socket that can hold a stick, sorry, but the end of the road is here, barring rubber piece use. A standard A or B type USB can't fit into LEGO proportioned holes.

Answer (score 3):

It's not deep enough, but depending on what the model is *for* it might be sufficient: a 2x1 brick with no center pin is almost exactly the right width/height for a USB plug. These are easy to find in transparent colours [but solid colours exist as well](https://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3065).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Caleb already explored the 'rebuild it in bricks' option, let me add a few other options.

1. There are a few LEGO products that have a Female USB slot built in. You could look at integrating these into your build. Most of them have an awkward shape though. E.g.

[LEGO Mindstorms EV3 brick](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=95646c01&name=Mindstorms%20EV3%20-%20Complete%20Brick&category=[Electric,%20Programmable]):

[image]

[LEGO Mindstorms NXT brick](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=53788&name=Mindstorms%20NXT%20-%20Complete%20Brick%20with%20Dark%20Bluish%20Gray%20Base&category=[Electric,%20Programmable]):

[image]

[LEGO Digital Camera](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=x86px1&name=Electric,%20Camera%20USB%20with%20Logo&category=[Electric]):

[image]

2. If you don't mind switching from a Female USB to a Male USB, you could buy one of these [USB Flash drives](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?G=flashdr16gb&name=USB%20Flash%20Drive%2016GB%20Brick&category=[Electronics]) and integrate it - it will look and act like a USB port and can connect (at least on the top as illustrated with the red 2x4 brick) to other LEGO pieces:

[image]